# Is there a word to describe someone who dislikes incompetence?

Tags: adjectives

I'm looking for a word or words to describe a person who dislikes incompetence (when someone can't do a job successfully), or those they deem ineffective in their work. It would also especially irk them if the person won't admit that they are incompetent/ineffective.

Comment: Is there anyone who _likes_ incompetence in others?

Answer (score 16):

He does not suffer fools gladly.

> **not suffer fools gladly** PHRASE
> Be impatient or intolerant toward people one regards as foolish or unintelligent.
> ‘he was a perfectionist who didn't suffer fools gladly’
> **Origin**
> With biblical allusion to 2 Cor. 11:19.
> [LEXICO](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/not_suffer_fools_gladly)

Comment: Very common in the UK - captures the idea exactly. I don't know about the US.

Comment: Also very common in the US.

Comment: My personal attitude puts a full stop after _fools_.

Answer (score 7):

**no-nonsense** (adj.) (also **take no nonsense**)

> That does not tolerate foolish or extravagant conduct; brisk,
> practical, businesslike. OED
> *His employees are..slavish devotees of their master's no-nonsense work ethic*

> Tolerating no nonsense : SERIOUS, BUSINESSLIKE
> *a no-nonsense manager*
>
> **nonsense** affected or impudent conduct
> ***took no nonsense** from subordinates*  [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no-nonsense)

> Not tolerating irrelevancies; direct, efficient, and practical
> *the
> no-nonsense tones of a stern parent.* [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/no-nonsense)

---

> Beyond this, although No Child Left Behind conveys the impression that
> it contains a **no-nonsense** approach to *incompetence* in education
> leadership, in reality, because of the tenure system, principals and
> staff who are fired will probably just transfer to other school
> districts. [W. H. Jeynes; *American Educational History*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Educational_History/j7hK-7CC7fMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=no-nonsense%20incompetence&pg=PA414&printsec=frontcover) .

> ...the newspaperman turned management expert was the tough-as-nails,
> **no-nonsense** businessman. [R. Parker; "State of the Industry"](https://books.google.com/books?id=BjoEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PT21&dq=no%20nonsense&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGkK-4lNHyAhXmF1kFHQCDBJQ4KBDoATAEegQICxAC#v=onepage&q=no%20nonsense&f=false)

> He called them the "Cheetah Generation"—Africa's new hope.
>
> "They do no relate to the old colonialist paradigm...They **brook no
> nonsense** about corruption, *inefficiency, incompetence*, or
> buffoonery." [A. J. Thakkar; *The Lion Awakes: Adventures in Africa's
> Economic Miracle*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Lion_Awakes/_q0nCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22no-nonsense%22%20incompetence&pg=PA103&printsec=frontcover)

> "...**take no nonsense** from any presumptuous hireling..." [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Tomorrow/EokSAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22take%20no%20nonsense%20from%20any%20presumptuous%20hireling%22).

---

It's been used in quite a few book titles. Among the work-related are:

[R. S. Sloma; ***No-Nonsense** Management: A General Manager's Primer*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/No_Nonsense_Management/fa5sOkUrprIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=no-nonsense%20management&printsec=frontcover)

[B. Allan; *The **No-Nonsense** Guide to Project Management*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_No_Nonsense_Guide_to_Project_Managem/NbstDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=no-nonsense%20management&printsec=frontcover)

[T. Gegax and P. Bolsta; *By the Seat of Your Pants: The **No-Nonsense** Business Management Guide*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/By_the_Seat_of_Your_Pants/0v4DPQAACAAJ?hl=en)

Comment: I think nonsense in this context may encompass deliberate behaviour whereas incompetence is not deliberate.

Comment: It certainly would *include* putting feet on the desk and throwing spitballs; however, some of the examples *specifically* refer to inefficiency and incompetence. And I believe these fall within the use in the book titles, which aren't just about getting employees to behave nicely.

Comment: I can see that there is an overlap between the two idioms

Answer (score 3):

"A stickler" or "a stickler for detail" is commonly used for someone who really wants to see things done precisely and accurately.

Answer (score 0):

meritocratic ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meritocratic))

> a system, organization, or society in which people are chosen and moved into positions of success, power, and influence on the basis of their demonstrated abilities and merit